# Is there any example that show ideal $I$ of $A$ is a ring ideal, but no algebra ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

**‎‎A ring ‎‎$‎R‎$‎ is said to be simple if ‎‎$‎R^{‎2} ‎\neq‎ 0‎‎$‎ and ‎‎$‎0‎‎$‎‎ and ‎‎$‎R‎$‎ are the only ideals of ‎‎$‎R‎$‎.**‎

‎‎‎‎Without assuming that ‎$‎A^{‎2} ‎\neq‎ 0‎‎$‎ it is possible that ‎‎$‎A‎$‎ has many ring ideals, but no‎ algebra ideals different from ‎‎$‎0‎‎$‎‎‎ and ‎$‎A‎$‎. For instance, take the 1-dimensional algebra‎ ‎$‎‎‎A = ‎‎\mathbb{R}‎a‎$‎ with trivial multiplication, i.e., ‎‎$‎a^{‎2} = 0‎‎$‎. Then clearly ‎‎$‎A‎$‎ has no algebra ideals
different from ‎‎$‎0‎‎$‎ and ‎‎$‎A‎$‎, but has plenty of ring ideals (say, ‎‎$‎‎\mathbb{Z}‎a‎$‎).‎‎
‎

> 1: Is there any example that show ideal $I$ of $A$ is a ring ideal, but no algebra ideal?

‎

**‎A nonzero unital algebra is said to be central if scalar multiples of unity are the only elements in its ‎center.‎‎‎**

> ‎2‎:‎ Are ‎$\mathbb{H},‎‎\mathbb{C}‎‎‎‎‎‎$‎ simple central ‎$‎\mathbb{R}‎‎$‎-‎‎‎‎algebras? ‎Is‎ ‎$‎\mathbb{C}‎‎‎‎‎‎$‎ simple central ‎$‎\mathbb{‎C‎}‎‎$‎-‎‎‎‎algebra?‎‎‎‎

Comment: For the first part of your question, you're going to have to explain what you mean by "algebra." For regular algebras, the usual definition puts a copy of the field in the ring, but the example you gave doesn't satisfy that. For the second part of your question, it's well known that $\mathbb H$ is a central simple $\mathbb R$ algebra, and obviously $F$ is a central simple $F$ algebra for any field. $\mathbb C$ is obviously *not* a central simple $\mathbb R$ algebra. The hardest one is proving $\mathbb H$ is a central simple $\mathbb R$ algebra, but you shouldn't hardly need help on the rest...

Answer (score 5):

In an *unital* algebra, a ring ideal is always an algebra ideal, because being closed under multiplication by arbitrary elements of the algebra implies being closed under multiplication by scalar multiples of $1$ and so closure under scalar multiplication.

There are non-unital examples of (1) though: Let $A$ be the $\mathbb R$-algebra of real polynomials whose constant term vanish, and let $I$ be the set of polynomials in $A$ whose first-degree coefficient is an integer. This is easily seen to be a *rng ideal*, but it is not an algebra ideal, because it's not closed under scalar multiplication.

$\mathbb C$ is obviously not central over $\mathbb R$ because it is commutative and so its own center, but not all complex numbers are real multiples of $1$!

On the other hand, $\mathbb H$ is central over $\mathbb R$, and is simple because it is a division ring.